# Store integer and float in numpy array in matrix form

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

The following code contains PostGIS query and get 'product', which includes integer and floats,

```
import numpy

k = 8
for i in cor_list:
    for l in cor_list:
        cur.execute(query, (i, l, False, False))
        element = cur.fetchall()
        product = sum([a[-1] for a in element[:-1]])
        print product
        ss = numpy.array(product, ndmin = 2)
kk = ss.reshape((k,k))
```

part of product looks like:

```
0
6460.51962839
16386.3142965
18349.9662043
13071.5492165
8349.95786602
3977.69337529
10471.7888158
6460.51962839
0
9925.79466809
11889.4465759
```

and I want to arrange these product in a numpy array which is 8 times 8, which could looks like,

[image]

but as I ran the code above, I got this error:

```
ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged
```

How to store integer and float generated by for-loop in numpy array in matrix form?

Comment: @AngusWilliams (1L, 1L)

Comment: product is integer or float, and as I ran `print product.shape`, error shows: `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'shape'`.

Comment: `ss` is just one of those `product` values.  Nothing in your loops is collecting the `product` values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can fix your code by doing something like this:

```
import numpy

product = []
k = 8
for i in cor_list:
    for l in cor_list:
        cur.execute(query, (i, l, False, False))
        element = cur.fetchall()
        product.append( sum([a[-1] for a in element[:-1]]) )
kk = numpy.array(product).reshape((k,k))
```